# Can't see Add Git integration link in Bluemix dashboard

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

I created a simple Node.js app on Bluemix. I want to push the code to devOps but I can't see the Add Git Integration on the right side of Routes as shown in the link

https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditor
Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that can cause the button to not be present is when IBM DevOps Services is down for maintenance or unreachable by Bluemix. DevOps Services provides the git integration capabilities, so if it is down, the options don't show.

Looking at my apps in Bluemix now, I can see the integration working. Have you tried again since and, if so, are you still not seeing the button?

Comment: Although this does point out a possible reason, you seem to be unsure. To give people information about their situation, please leave a comment. Questions should not be answered with another question

Comment: I must have 50 rep to comment... furthermore, I have a great deal of confidence that this was the problem as I'm literally looking at the button that was missing in the UI right now... feels like an answer to me.

Comment: I was doing a review (which lead me to this question). I didn't think the 50+ rep applied to commenting on questions, but as I've been looking, it seems to be a huge problem. I have posted it in the meta exchange. Sorry for the inconvienence. I'll remove the downvote until I'm sure its justified or not. EDIT: Its saying my vote is locked until the post is edited; edit it in some way if you want me to remove the downvote. (seems to be quite a few conflicts with stack's filters and permissions system /:)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code originated in a developer client machine and then you cf Pushed to BLuemix The preferred worflow is to get the code into DevOps from the client and then push DevOps into Bluemix.  See slide 44 in this presentation.  http://www.slideshare.net/fe01134/bluemix-julymeetup2014-v2